# Ubuntu 22.04 Too Slow

Tags: 22.04

I am also having issues with Ubuntu 22.04 running to slow on my server. It was installed fresh.

The main issues is during software updates or installs, the system hangs occasionally while installing various software. If I install anything, it undergoes long pauses in unpacking some software.

Server: HP Z440. Xeon E5 1650 v3 processor, 32 GB RAM. GPU: nvidia gtx 1080.

The updates take forever and are really annoying if anything. Anyone have any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: please post the numbers how long does the updates take,as your quetion is now it is only your opinion that you think it takes too long to update your system.as of now the ubuntu 22.04 still have some stuff that needs to be fixed but it will get better over time and the updates will take less time as ubuntu 22.04 gets more mature.

Comment: How are you connected? WiFi? What's your MTU? Find out with `ip link`

Comment: Is this a virtual machine by any chance?

Comment: Can you detail what you are using for swap?  `swapon -a` is sufficient

Comment: Not a virtual machine. Connected via hard-wire ethernet. Tested speed yesterday on the server and it was approx 400 mbps.

Comment: I am not going to make a big deal out of it as Trond says, give it a little time to work itself out.

Comment: Hi - you may want to add the hardware specs to the question title or it may be ignored as being too general.

Comment: This is a recurring question in here. And people keep saying it's not related to 22.04. I have the same issue. Upgrade from 21.10 and slow wifi on 2 laptops.